# Swift generic of an item conforming to protocol or a list of items

Tags: swift, generics, swift4

I'm writing a class that takes a generic.

I need it to be conforming to a protocol or to be a list of items conforming to that protocol

My class decliration:

```
class LiveData<T> where T: Actor
```

Now it only accepts single items conforming to Actor, I want to be able to also have the option to pass an array of items conforming to Actor

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problems by using 2 initializers. You can initialize LiveData with a single Actor or an array of Actors.

```
class LiveData<T> where T: Actor {
    var actors: [T]

    init(actor: T) {
        self.actors = [actor]
    }

    init(actors: [T]) {
        self.actors = actors
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the T is the return type, I don't pass it to the initializer...

Comment: @MarioMouris Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean? If you don't nail down `T` in `init`, there's no way for the class to know what it is later. You're going to have to do something to establish it in `init`.